# What kind of hand-crafted features do top performing family of engines use to evaluate a position?

Tags: engines, stockfish, evaluation, alphazero

[AlphaZero paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01815.pdf) which introduced the engine which allegidly outperformed stockfish mentioned the following:

> These programs evaluate positions using features handcrafted by human
>   grandmasters and carefully tuned weights, combined with a
>   high-performance alpha-beta search that expands a vast search tree
>   using a large number of clever heuristics and domain-specific
>   adaptations.

In particular I am interested in a claim about **features handcrafted by human
grandmasters**. The paper didn't provide any examples, neither it references anything here. To make the question less ambiguous, let's narrow the scope of programs to just a couple of [best performing](http://www.computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/4040/rating_list_all.html) families of engines (stockfish, sugar, komodo, houdini)

So my question is: what kind of hand-crafted features do top performing family of engines use to evaluate a position?

Comment: You're a programmer right? Why not look at evaluate.cpp in Stockfish source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper is right. Traditional chess engines use a set of tedious hand-crafted features for positional evaluation.

I'd say nothing surprising, to name a fews (I can't name everything):

- Mobility bonus
- Outpost bonus
- Attack bonus
- Rook on the seventh rank
- Material advantage
- Minor pieces behind pawn

> https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/master/src/evaluate.cpp

If you take a look at the source code, it's quite complicated. Difficult programming for something that is understood even by chess beginners.

What about **replacing** the entire file with a deep neural network? Training a network is easier than tweaking those numbers in the file.